# Resetting WAMP Server (PHP and Apache) configurations

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

Is there a way to reset to the original configurations for PHP and Apache on WAMP Server and avoiding a fresh re-install? I tried to upgrade my PHP and Apache versions from VC9 (PHP 5.4.16, Apache 2.4.4) to VC11 (PHP 5.5.10, Apache 2.4.9) but I managed to mess the whole thing up, so if I can just reset configurations, that'd be great.

I have already removed the Apache 2.4.9 and PHP 5.5.10 folders, leaving the original versions folders.

Comment: You are really not very specific about what you did, but try `right click wampmanager -> refresh` If you are lucky that may help

Comment: (General note on formatting: so you know, backticks to produce inline background colouring is generally for code or console input/output. It looks nice, but it's not really appropriate for names of software or versions, and is likely to create edit work over time.)

Comment: @halfer That highlighted section was for a mouse action and menu selection. Does that not count as a console input/output?

Comment: @halfer No sweat and ditto :)

Comment: How did you perform this upgrade?   "Configuration" to me would include .config and .ini files, whereas you are referencing changing binaries and potentially many other files.

I recommend you detail how you performed this upgrade, and also provide us with the error logs that are output when you try to run PHP or Apache.  From there we can really start breaking this issue apart.